# WordPress Multisite: Login to all subsites at once

Tags: multisite, wp-admin, login

I've setup a WP multisite network (with subdomains). I'd like to know if there's an option/plugin/code for logging in to all sites at once. For example, you login to `example.com/wp-admin`, you'll be automatically logged in to `site1.example.com` & `site2.example.com` etc. Is this possible with PHP Code, or is there any plugin? I'd like to know how I can solve this. Thanks in advance to everyone who gives a perfect solution.

Comment: It works that way in subdirectories networks, log in once, logged in everywhere. but I believe subdomains networks it doesn't work because the cookies save to the whole domain.

Comment: @DavidSword Is there a plugin or PHP code to change that cookie setting?